# How do I customize the Code Analysis Dictionary for a C# project in VS2010 Professional?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I've tried following the instructions [that the warning message links to](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb514188.aspx), but there is no entry for `CodeAnalysisDictionary` in the Build Action list. I've tried manually editing the `.csproj` file in a similar way to that suggested here for C++ files -- I've added

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Content Include="CustomDictionary.xml" />
</ItemGroup>
```

after one of the other `ItemGroup` elements, but that doesn't seem to work either.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the [FxCop Integrator](http://fxcopintegrator.codeplex.com/) extension.  It allows you to right-click on the Solution and choose *Code Analysis*.  The other option is *More Tasks*.  Within that *More Tasks* menu is the ability to edit **Edit FxCop Dictionary**.  When I performed the edit, it created a new *Solution Folder* called *Code Analysis* containing a new XML file called *FxCopDictionary.xml*.  This XML file is set up as one would expect the *CustomDictionary.xml* file to look like.

Hope this helps someone out there!

BTW - there's another similar question here:  [How to get the FxCop custom dictionary to work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359290/how-to-get-the-fxcop-custom-dictionary-to-work/12771062#12771062)